# Setting Autocompletefield rowheight

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde

[image: screenshoot]

I am using drawListRow to repaint the autocomplete field, but I'm having trouble to set it's field height, here is my code:

```
autoCustomer = new AutoCompleteField(custList, style){
        public void drawListRow(ListField clistField, Graphics g,
                int index, int y, int width) {

                BasicFilteredListResult result = (BasicFilteredListResult) 
                        autoCustomer.get(clistField, index);//);
                if (result == null)
                    return;
                    String[] stringArray = parseMessage(result._object.toString(), Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN),fontSize, width-30);
                    int i;
                    int yCoord = 0;
                    int xCoord = 0;
                    //int rowHeight = (stringArray.length * fontHeight)+3;
                    clistField.setRowHeight((stringArray.length * fontHeight)+3); //already did this, but it won't work
                    System.out.println(stringArray.length);
                    g.setFont( Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN,fontSize,Ui.UNITS_px));
                    for(i = 0;i<stringArray.length;i++){
                        yCoord = y + (fontHeight*(i));
                        if(i>0)
                            xCoord = 20;       
                        g.drawText(stringArray[i].trim() , xCoord, yCoord, (DrawStyle.LEFT | DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS | DrawStyle.TOP ),  width-20);
                    }

        }
```

What should I do to make proper row height with this autocomplete ?

Comment: I have been trying to create text boxes just like the one u have created.Can you please guide how to develop one of those.Do check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589513/creating-advanced-user-interfaces-blackberry) on how i went about trying but couldn't find any luck with it.

Comment: which one ? is it the autocomplete ?

Comment: Yes.I want my text fields to have boxes for grabbing input.Most of the samples i have come across demonstrate using borders that span the entire width of the screen.Can you suggest a possible way of how you went about developing these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I unintentionally found the answer, the first argument is index of the list and the second is the height.
The documentation doesn't mention about this, I only found setRowHeight(int arg0, int arg1) in the documentation of class in eclipse.
The solution is simple

```
clistField.setRowHeight(index,(stringArray.length * fontHeight)+3);
```